# PHP - Google API (Beta) getting bearer token

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have been using the Google API client in PHP for a project with google assistant where I need to post transaction updates.

See : https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/dev-guide-physical-custom#6_send_order_updates

I use the server-to-server procedure to connect : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

I didn't found any support for Transactions or Actions. So I can't just call a service like the example. My goal is just to get the bearer token back and code the update based on the documentation of the transactions.

So I made this code :

```
$client = new Google_Client();              
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.'path/to/file/');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();                                 
$client->setApplicationName('Update_Orders_Test');                                 
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation']);
$auth = $client->authorize();
```

But with this code I can't get the bearer token in the $client object or the $auth object. But I do not have any error too. The path to the JSON file is correct, there is an error if the file doesn't exist.

Here is the client object :

```
{
  "auth": null,
  "http": {},
  "cache": {},
  "token": null,
  "config": {
    "application_name": "Update_Orders_Test",
    "base_path": "https://www.googleapis.com",
    "client_id": "",
    "client_secret": "",
    "redirect_uri": null,
    "state": null,
    "developer_key": "",
    "use_application_default_credentials": true,
    "signing_key": null,
    "signing_algorithm": null,
    "subject": null,
    "hd": "",
    "prompt": "",
    "openid.realm": "",
    "include_granted_scopes": null,
    "login_hint": "",
    "request_visible_actions": "",
    "access_type": "online",
    "approval_prompt": "auto",
    "retry": [],
    "cache_config": [],
    "token_callback": null,
    "jwt": null
  },
  "logger": null,
  "deferExecution": false,
  "requestedScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation"
  ]
}
```

As you can see the basic information are set but not the one relative to the json file.

Is there something I did wrong with this code ?